# Why do I have "private access" error even if I didn't return any field?

Tags: java, oop

I am learning OOP in Java. When finishing coding and compiling it, the compiler shows that this Manager class has **private access** to the Photographer class. I've been working on for a whole night, but I still cannot find the problem. Anyone could tell me how to fix it?

```
public class Manager
{

    private ArrayList<Assignment> toDoList;
    private ArrayList<Photographer> employees;
    public Manager()
    {
    this.toDoList = new ArrayList<Assignment>();
    this.employees = new ArrayList<Photographer>();
    }

    public void hire(String photographer)
    {
        employees.add(new Photographer(photographer));

    }

    public void giveOutAssignments()
    {
        int maxId;  
        if(toDoList.size()!=0 && employees.size()!=0){

            for(Photographer p: employees){
                maxId = 0;

                //get highest priority
                for(int i = 1; i<toDoList.size();i++){
                    //just check the unfinished assigns
                    if(!toDoList.get(i).getStatus()){
                        if(toDoList.get(i).getPriority()>toDoList.get(maxId).getPriority())
                            maxId = i;
                    }
                }
                //take the highest priority
                Assignment currentAssign = toDoList.get(maxId);

                //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
                p.takePicture(currentAssign.getDescription());  

                //set it as finished
                toDoList.get(maxId).setStatus();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the Photographer class:
        public class Photographer
        {
            private Map photos;
            private String name;

```
    public Photographer(String name)
    {
    photos = new HashMap(); // An important line. Must go in the constructor.
    readPhotos(); // A very important line. this must go in the Photographer
    // constructor so that the photographer will be able to take Pictures.
    this.name = name;   
    }

    private String takePicture(String description)
    {
    return photos.get(description);
    }

    private void readPhotos()
    {
    Pattern commentPattern = Pattern.compile("^//.*");
    Pattern photoPattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9\\.]+) (.*)");
    try
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("photos.txt"));

        while (in.hasNextLine())
        {
        String line = in.nextLine();

        Matcher commentMatcher = commentPattern.matcher(line);
        Matcher photoMatcher = photoPattern.matcher(line);
        if (commentMatcher.find())
        {
            // This line of the file is a comment. Ignore it.
        }
        else if (photoMatcher.find())
        {
            String fileName = photoMatcher.group(1);
            String description = photoMatcher.group(2);
            photos.put(description, fileName);
        }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: `takePicture` is declared `private`, it is inaccessible from any other context other than `Photographer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`takePicture` is declared `private`, it is inaccessible from any other context other than `Photographer`...

```
private String getDescription() {
```

change it to `public`...

```
public String getDescription() {
```

Take a look at [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more details

ps-

I also had an issue with the return type of `takePicture` in `Photographer`...

```
private String takePicture(String description)
{
    return photos.get(description);
}
```

And had to change to something more like...

```
public String takePicture(String description) {
    return (String)photos.get(description);
}
```

Comment: But I called takePicture() by a Photographer object. Shouldn't it work?

Comment: No, `takePicture` is `private` to `Photographer` ONLY, so ONLY `Photographer` can call it.  You are calling the method from the context the `Manager` context.  That's the point of method accessors, to control who can call what...

Comment: Hello. I am new to Stack Overflow. Could you tell me why my question is negative vote? Did I ask something wrong?

Comment: Down voting can sometimes be very subjective, the probable cause was people saw the question as solvable through more research on your part. I think people forget that OO is difficult subject that can trap the new developer